# Calculate the 1st Brillouin zone with given lattice basis vectors

Tags: physics, geometry, lattices

Given two basis vectors in the 2-dimensional momentum space `b1, b2`, I want to write a function that returns the 1st Brillouin zone:

```
BrillouinZone[b1_, b2_] := ...
```

which is defined as the region made of points that are closer to the origin of the reciprocal lattice than they are to any other reciprocal lattice points (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone)). For example, the reciprocal basis vectors of the square lattice are

```
b1 = {2 Pi, 0};
b2 = {0, 2 Pi};
```

The function `BrillouinZone` should return a region that is the same as the square

```
Polygon[{Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, -Pi}, {Pi, -Pi}]
```

How to achieve this (efficiently) in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BrillouinZone[b1_, b2_] := 
  CanonicalizePolygon[First[Select[
   MeshPrimitives[
    VoronoiMesh[Catenate@Table[i b1 + j b2, {i, -1, 1}, {j, -1, 1}]], 2], 
   RegionMember[#, {0, 0}] &]]];

b1 = {2 Pi, 0};
b2 = {0, 2 Pi};
bz = BrillouinZone[b1, b2]

Show[Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], bz}], Axes -> True]
```

[image]